# How to not match character in capturing group

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a capturing grp numbered 2 that catches a number but i need the regex to match everything except what's in \2
I tried [^\2] but it's still matching it

Regex:

```
##[^\n]*\n## \(CR (\d)\) RM (\d): [^\n]*\n##[^\n]*\n\(CR \1\) SM \2: [^\n]*\n(##[^\n]*\n\(CL **[^\2]**\) RM \2: [^\n]*\n)+
```

Text:

> ### (Chat room 1) Received message from client 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> ### (CR 1) RM 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> ### (Chat room 1) Sent message to all connected clients except client 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> (CR 1) SM 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> ### (Client 1) Received message from client 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> (CL 3) RM 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> ### (Client 1) Received message from client 4: Nice to meet you!
>
> (CL 4) RM 4: Nice to meet you!

I want the last two lines not to be matched

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2cGxor/1)

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: But there is no\ or 2 in your text anywhere...?

Comment: Oh, capture group 2...

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a negative lookahead and then match a digit `(?!\2)\d` to not match the last line

```
##[^\n]*\n## \(CR (\d)\) RM (\d): [^\n]*\n##[^\n]*\n\(CR \1\) SM \2: [^\n]*\n(##[^\n]*\n\(CL (?!\2)\d\) RM \2: [^\n]*\n)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i1llMI/1)

As the last group is a repeated capturing group, you could also make it non capturing `(?:` if you don`t need the group itself.

Repeating a captured group will only capture the value of the last iteration.

```
(?:##[^\n]*\n\(CL (?!\2)\d\) RM \2: [^\n]*\n)+
^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AYHXfG/1)

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe an expression similar to,

```
##[^\n]*\n## \(CR (\d)\) RM (\d): [^\n]*\n##[^\n]*\n\(CR \1\) SM \2: [^\n]*\n((?!##[^\n]*\n\(CL \2\) RM \2: [^\n]*\n)##[^\n]*\n\(CL .*?\) RM \2: [^\n]*\n)+
```

might be OK to look into, but I'm not so sure if it would be close to what you have in mind.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6PcOAB/1)

Comment: all the rest of the regex is working perfectly as i wrote it cause it's matching lines in a big output text for an assignment i have but i just need to know how to match anything but what's in the capture group

Comment: I'm sorry the two ** came from copying the code here, i have linked a demo to make it more easier